# Test Coverage for Individual Object

Tags: batch, individual

We may all know that Salesforce introduced the Individual object in 2018 because of the introduction of GDPR. Here what I need is I need to create a test class for the Individual object because I written a batch in Individual object. But for Individual object we must need to activate it in Salesforce environment. Is there any way to activate and test the Individual object in the test context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to create dataset for the 'Individual' object in the test context.

```
Map <String, Schema.SObjectType > sObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType individualType = sObjects.get('Individual');
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mSourceFields = 
individualType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
SObject individualObject01 = individualType.newSObject();
SObject individualObject02 = individualType.newSObject();
individualObject01.put(mSourceFields.get('Name'), 'Individual 1');
individualObject02.put(mSourceFields.get('Name'), 'Individual 2');

List<SObject> lstIndividual = new List<SObject>();
lstIndividual.add(individualObject01);
lstIndividual.add(individualObject02);
insert lstIndividual;
```

But when you package the feature of the Individual Batch, In the packaging org you must need to activate Individual object manually to pass the test class for the Individual BATCH.

Comment: Correct! I have written something similar. In your test class, you should first check if the Individual object exists in the org (probably after line 2, you can check if "individualType" is null or not) - if it's not in the org, then you can skip the rest of the test execution. (This is assuming this code might be packaged and exist in orgs that will never have the Individual object enabled.)

Comment: Yes you are correct. we can check it like , Boolean isIndividualEnable = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey('Individual');

Comment: @RobertWatson I encountered another problem here that in the test context the Individual object is not available even after I enable it in the org. But in the real environment it have. Did I missed anything?

Comment: I am not sure, that's strange. Perhaps ensure that the test class is on the correct API version? The Individual object was released in v42.0

Comment: Yes. The issue cam because of the lower version.